# Unable to find a target named `ProjectName`

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, cocoapods

I added new pod in PodFile and ran command

```
pod install
```

It deleted all previous pods and failed with following error

```
Unable to find a target named `ProjectName`
```

However I recovered all deleted pods by using `Git`, but now my project is not being compiled, it's giving me the following error:

```
/Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_Name-fhktwvetozjdorboqdzfwlpzrcyw/Build/Intermediates/Project_Name.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project_Name.build/Script-D7BB987C75C5AEC6033AA28E.sh:
/Users/userName/Desktop/iOS_Workspace/Project_Name/Pods/Target Support
Files/Pods-Project_Name/Pods-Project_Name-resources.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad
interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tried every solution regarding pods, but neither worked for me.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does your podfile look like?

Comment: its like executable file, not like normal text file, I don't know why.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

After spending hours on Google just opened Podfile and found that project name is wrong. So I have just written **correct project name** in `Podfile` and issue has been resolved.

**Before:**

```
target 'Wrong Project Name' do
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
end
```

**After:**

```
target 'Correct Project Name' do
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
end
```

Comment: This happened to me after renaming a project, I failed to update this line in the podfile. This answer saved me a lot of time, thanks!

Comment: This happened to me after removing the Test target from XCode, this solution worked for me, thanks!

Comment: thanks for the solution...

Comment: Oh man thank you so much

Comment: You laid down hours of your life so that I wouldn't have to, for that I thank you.

Answer (score 13):

According to the error, you specify a target named `ProjectName` but this does not exist in your project. Read the [podfile syntax reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#target) carefully and make sure you add the right target name (in my case it's called `Tester`:)

[image]

Comment: I just replaced my project name with "ProjectName", to hide my project name.

Comment: Ok, but are you sure you are using the correct target name? Or maybe you run `pod install` while at the wrong path? Also, try to google `/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter:` since that `^M` looks weird

Comment: This is WORKED FOR ME

Answer (score 4):

It is due to target name changed.

just opened Podfile and replace target name with new target name.

(In my case “GoogleMapSample” was “Map Sample”,

“GoogleMapSampleTests” was “Map SampleTests”,

“GoogleMapSampleUITests” was “Map SampleUITests”,

means I just replace “Map Sample” with “GoogleMapSample” for all targets)

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'GoogleMapSample' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4’
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'


  # Pods for GoogleMapSample

  target 'GoogleMapSampleTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'GoogleMapSampleUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Take backup of podfile (copy paste at specified location).
2. Remove pod file. Move to Trash (from) Xcode.
3. Go to terminal, After locating your pods directory, Hit: pod init
4. Paste contents from backup-ed file (1st step)...Copy only pod libs. ex. pod 'Firebase/Core'
5. pod install
6. Re-start your project then open YourProjectName.xcworkspace.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the target name was the same,
but it was case sensitive wrong.
"myTarget" // podfile
"MyTarget" // Xcode

Comment: Mine have been copied and posted and are 100% correct, still getting error.. the error even says couldn't find 'A', found 'A' ...?

Answer (score 1):

make sure your current name for project in Podfile Matching with right name

```
target 'Project name' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Project name

pod 'SwiftMessages'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of schemas like below. So, we should map a schema in pod file.

**Wrong** : target 'MobileBranch' do

**Correct** : target 'Test-MobileBranch' do

**Correct** : target 'Main-MobileBranch' do

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are here in 2022 using SwiftUI, I just uncomment the line and specified the latest iOS version. I am using Xcode 14.0.1.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '16.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### FIXED

Just I changed `App` to the correct name of the product which is `Mevenda`:

```rb
target 'Mevenda' do
  capacitor_pods
  # Add your Pods here
  pod 'FirebaseStorage'
end
```

[image]